# PHP - mysqli_query count always returns 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am a kind of a beginner in this ...

For some reason This mysqli_query count always returns 1

```
$class_number = $_POST['class'];

$check_class_number = mysqli_query($con, " SELECT * FROM `Academy` WHERE ClassNumber = '".$class_number."' ");

echo count($check_class_number);
```

The current situation in my MySql table:

1- I have only two rows

2- Under the column `ClassNumber` I have the same `value` 150701-100

I simply need to count the number of the ClassNumber 150701-100, which suppose in my case to returns 2. However as I mentions it always returns 1, even if I added more rows.

My final intention is to add this logical if to the code

```
 if(count($check_class_number)>0){
                  echo "exists.";

                  }else{
                  echo "It does not exist.";

                  }
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you want to first fetch your data, before you count them

Comment: use mysqli_num_rows($check_class_number);

Comment: `count()` is for arrays. `mysqli_query()` returns a `mysqli_result` object, not an array.

Comment: `mysql_query` returns a statement handle/object. it'll naturally count to `1`, since it's a SINGLE handle/object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysqli_num_rows to count the number of rows returned from the query. count() will only work on an array.

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($check_class_number)>0) {
      echo "exists.";
 } else {
      echo "It does not exist.";
 }
```

Comment: Thak you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do as OllyTenerife, or use `$check_class_number` to get the num of rows.

```
if($check_class_number->num_rows > 0)
{
     doSmt();
}
else
{
    echo "Does not exist.";
}
```